# Calculate average only for date columns that is before "today"

Tags: google-sheets

Supposed "today" is 8/1 and I have the following cells:

```
6/20/2018 19:00:00 | 6/27/2018 18:00:00 | 8/8/2018 19:00:00
===========================================================
1                  | 2                  | 3
```

How do I create a formula where I want to calculate the average of row 2 *only* for columns that before "today" (ie the average of `1` and `2`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in a cell on the same sheet:

```
=query(query(transpose(A1:C2),"select * "),"select avg(Col2) where Col1 < now()")
```

Change the date in B1 to less than today to average A2 and B2.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted your query to `=query(transpose(A1:C2),"select avg(Col2) where Col1 < now() label avg(Col2) ''")` since I didn't want the header labeled "avg" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=AVERAGEIF(1:1,"<6/27/2018",2:2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to hardcode the number of values to take an average. For example, there could be 10 dates with 10 values and today could mean the first 7 columns.